# Fitting branch models with godon

Tags: phylogenetics, codon, godon

Is it possible to fit branch models [(Yang and Nielsen, 1998)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/PL00006320) in [godon](https://bitbucket.org/Davydov/godon/src)? That is, the model which averages over all sites, as opposed to the branch site models?

Comment: For those VTCing this - Bioinformatics.SE is the specified help forum for the godon package. If you've got a problem, take it up with [the meta](https://bioinformatics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240/im-a-bioinfo-software-developer-and-i-would-like-to-use-bioinformatics-se-as-t)

Comment: The votes to close are because your question lacks a lot of detail.

Comment: And yet, it has all of the information necessary for the question to be answered.

Comment: Voted to open, because it's exactly the type of questions we aim for - concise, concrete and answerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Branch-models are currently not implemented in godon. In the PAML manual Ziheng Yang writes:

> This model is very parameter-rich and its use is discouraged.

This was one of the reasons I did not implement it.

*Disclaimer: I am the author of godon.*